# Print Currency Number Format in PHP

Tags: php, formatting, currency

I have some price values to display in my page.

I am writing a function which takes the float price and returns the formatted currency val with currency code too..

For example, `fnPrice(1001.01)` should print `$ 1,000.01`

Comment: Check out https://www.geekgong.com/formatting-currency-values-in-php/ for a nice little tut on this.

Answer (score 150, accepted):

The easiest answer is [`number_format()`](http://www.php.net/number_format).

```
echo "$ ".number_format($value, 2);
```

If you want your application to be able to work with multiple currencies and locale-aware formatting (`1.000,00` for some of us Europeans for example), it becomes a bit more complex.

There is [`money_format()`](http://www.php.net/money_format) but it doesn't work on Windows and relies on `setlocale()`, which is rubbish in my opinion, because it requires the installation of (arbitrarily named) locale packages on server side.

If you want to seriously internationalize your application, consider using a full-blown internationalization library like Zend Framework's [Zend_Locale](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.locale.html) and [Zend_Currency](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.currency.html).

Comment: For negative values you would get something like $-123.45, proper formatting should be -$123.45 however.

Comment: @ZurabWeb did you find fix around this?

Comment: @kimbarcelona  
    $sign = "-";
    $amount = "-500";

    if(strpos($amount, $sign) !== false){
         l.trim($amount, $sign);
        echo "-$ ".number_format($intval(amount), 2);}

Answer (score 70):

with the intl extension in PHP 5.3+, you can use the [NumberFormatter](http://php.net/numberformatter) class:

```
$amount = '12345.67';

$formatter = new NumberFormatter('en_GB',  NumberFormatter::CURRENCY);
echo 'UK: ', $formatter->formatCurrency($amount, 'EUR'), PHP_EOL;

$formatter = new NumberFormatter('de_DE',  NumberFormatter::CURRENCY);
echo 'DE: ', $formatter->formatCurrency($amount, 'EUR'), PHP_EOL;
```

which prints :

```
 UK: €12,345.67
 DE: 12.345,67 €
```

Comment: So important to have a solution that doesn't require converting to a float first. So dangerous to use a float with currency.

Answer (score 10):

sprintf() is the PHP function for all sorts of string formatting
http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php

I use this function:

```
function formatDollars($dollars){
  return '$ '.sprintf('%0.2f', $dollars);
}
```

Comment: this won't add commas (thousands separators)

Comment: Forgive the gravedig. You can wrap the `$dollars` (in the `sprintf()`) in a `number_format()`. That'll add the commas

Answer (score 7):

I built this little function to automatically format anything into a nice currency format.

```
function formatDollars($dollars)
{
    return "$".number_format(sprintf('%0.2f', preg_replace("/[^0-9.]/", "", $dollars)),2);
}
```

**Edit**

It was pointed out that this does not show negative values. I broke it into two lines so it's easier to edit the formatting. Wrap it in parenthesis if it's a negative value:

```
function formatDollars($dollars)
{
    $formatted = "$" . number_format(sprintf('%0.2f', preg_replace("/[^0-9.]/", "", $dollars)), 2);
    return $dollars < 0 ? "({$formatted})" : "{$formatted}";
}
```

Comment: This doens't retain negative values

Comment: This is true.  I've updated the function to include negative number support.  Thanks @FlyingNimbus

Answer (score 4):

Reference Link : https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php

```
$amount = 1235.56
echo number_format($amount, 2, '.', ',');
```

**The output is : 1,235.56**

If you don't need comma in output.Please remove comma inside function.

For example

```
$amount = 1235.56
echo number_format($amount, 2, '.', '');
```

**The output is : 1235.56**

Answer (score 3):

From the [docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php)

```
<?php

$number = 1234.56;

// english notation (default)
$english_format_number = number_format($number);
// 1,235

// French notation
$nombre_format_francais = number_format($number, 2, ',', ' ');
// 1 234,56

$number = 1234.5678;

// english notation without thousands separator
$english_format_number = number_format($number, 2, '.', '');
// 1234.57

?>
```

Answer (score 2):

(PHP 5 >= 5.3.0, PHP 7, PHP 8, PECL intl >= 1.0.0)

```
$fmt = new NumberFormatter( 'de_DE', NumberFormatter::CURRENCY );
echo $fmt->formatCurrency(1234567.891234567890000, "EUR")."\n";
echo $fmt->formatCurrency(1234567.891234567890000, "RUR")."\n";
```

output will be

```
1.234.567,89 €
1.234.567,89 RUR
```

https://www.php.net/manual/en/numberformatter.formatcurrency.php

Comment: According to the [PHP Docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.money-format.php): *This function has been **DEPRECATED** as of PHP 7.4.0, and REMOVED as of PHP 8.0.0. Relying on this function is highly discouraged.*

Comment: I have updated it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

PHP has a function called `money_format` for doing this. Read about this [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.money-format.php).

Comment: this function money_format does not work on php version 7.1

Comment: this function is deprecated in 7.4 and removed from 8.0