# Get order item line total formatted in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, orders, items

I've this code on my Website:

```
$order_items = $order->get_items();
foreach ( $order_items as $item_id => $item ) {
    $item_total = wc_get_order_item_meta( $item_id, '_line_total', true );
}
```

This returns the item total as a float value. But how can I get this now as a formatted value?

Currently: 1500
Goal: 1.500,00 €

Is there a function for this or do I need to write my own code to receive this result?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Print Currency Number Format in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4013950/print-currency-number-format-in-php)

Comment: Sure, [`wc_price()`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/function-wc_price.html).

Comment: @executable Don''t be a twit. I've asked if there is a function for this in WooCommerce. I know how to do it with PHP.

Comment: @BenM Thanks! I'll try that :)

Comment: You didn't asked for WooCommerce in your question...

Comment: @executable "WooCommerce: Get order item total formated"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use [`WC_Abstract_Order` `get_formatted_line_subtotal()`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Abstract_Order.html#1570-1589) dedicated method this way:

```
foreach ( $order->get_items() as $item_id => $item ) {
    echo $order->get_formatted_line_subtotal( $item );
}
```

Tested and works.

> It's already used by Woocommerce on the related templates and it handles everything needed.

---

You could also use [`WC_Order_Item_Product` `get_subtotal()` or `get_total()`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Order_Item_Product.html) methods with `wc_price()` formatting price function like:

```
foreach ( $order->get_items() as $item_id => $item ) {
    echo wc_price( $item->get_subtotal() ); // Non discounted
    echo wc_price( $item->get_total() ); // Discounted
}
```

Comment: Returned 0,00 € in my case. Strange.

Comment: @Mr.Jo That is not possible as this is used [on all woocommerce templates involving Orders items](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/release/3.5/templates/order/order-details-item.php#L46) … So that means that if your look in order view you will get also 0? simply not possible

Comment: My fault. Works!

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for the [`wc_price()`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/function-wc_price.html) function:

> Format the price with a currency symbol.

For example:

```
<?php wc_price($price) ?>
```